# Vertically Center Align Images and Text in a List

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, woocommerce

Here's the page http://www.theplasticsdepot.co.uk/product-category/drains/underground-pipes-and-fittings/ I'm having issues with. For clarity, I put a border around each item.

The `<ul>` has a class name of `et-products`

I would like each list item to be vertically centred at the very least so it just looks "right".

**Otherwise**, **ideally** and if at all possible, I'd like them to at least be aligned properly because if I don't use the CSS below, all sorts of strange floating occurs due to the various image sizes

```
ul.et-products li {
   border:1px solid #ccc;
   height:385px;
   padding:5px; margin:10px;
}
```

Comment: display:block; is tried ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: Your link does not work. The domain is private.

Comment: It does work and it's not private

Comment: I've started a browsershots.org for the link, and this is what's coming up: http://browsershots.org/http://www.theplasticsdepot.co.uk/product-category/drains/underground-pipes-and-fittings/ Just thought you should know that it's being blocked somewhere along the way for some people. This may be an issue you may want to look into if you're losing customers because we can't load your website.

Comment: Ok thanks - that is indeed worrying, considering other sites and people can access it. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```css
ul.et-products li a{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    height:385px;
    width: 200px; 
   }
ul.et-products li h3{
      margin-top:10px;
   }
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r93dM/3/

Comment: ur url is not working..its getting 404 error so i didt saw ur website,give the correct url

Comment: sorry its not working.try this one. ul.et-products li img{ vertical-align:middle;}

Comment: Almost there but the text has disappeared

Comment: in ur first li there is no text see the next li

Comment: In my source code, there is text but I can't see any when I run it. I have checked in Chrome and FireFox

Comment: k it will be appear behind the image use margin-top as high vaule

Answer (score 1):

add: `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` to your `ul.et-products li`

This should vertical center everything in your `li`'s

EDIT*********

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r93dM/1/

`float:left` was stopping the vertical align from working. I removed this and also added `<br>` to the `li`'s so they can still drop down instead of going horizontal

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of your list please?

Comment: Does work on jsFiddle but not on the site, there must be some other code breaking it! http://jsfiddle.net/r93dM/1/ worked better as http://jsfiddle.net/r93dM/2/ lists them all in a row

Comment: must be the width of the space that the list is in. Maybe you can figure out how many products fit in horizontally and the `<br>` the right one to knock the list down to the next line? sorry if that sounds confusing.

Answer (score 0):

use `table` tag instead of `ul li` this will work perfectly `vertical-align:middle`.
other solution is give css `display:table` to ul but this is not sure it's working or not.

i updated your jsfiddle not look it

http://jsfiddle.net/r93dM/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul.et-products li {
  vertical-align:middle

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you better try this code in your page,
        ul.et-products li {
       border:1px solid #ccc;
       height:385px;
       padding:5px; margin:10px;

```
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    }
```